# User Id Invalid - uninformative error after a fresh installation

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I've installed CRM 2013, DB, SSRS and the extensions. After that, I've created an organization. When I attempt to access the newly created organization I'm getting the error as shown below.

The information's as helpful as a chocolate teapot and I have no idea how to proceed. When I misspell the name, I'm getting the error that web page isn't found, so I'm getting the impression that something is up and running.

Suggestions?!

[image]

**Update**

After enabling the Dev errors. Browser says "user id invalid".

Comment: try to post at microsoft forums (crm deployment) http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=crmdeployment because it's a question not related to programming doesn't fit stackoverflow

Comment: Agree with Guido Preite, but if you want to investigate yourself. I would recommend you to check application event log and also enable the Dev errors on CRM. http://mayankp.wordpress.com/2010/09/11/dynamic-crm-troubleshooting-methods-for-any-crm-issue/

Comment: @Scorpion Agree with both of you. The error log gives me just "user id invalid". That can be 1000 different things, though. And the forum that Guido hints on isn't very quick with responses. Good link, though, which I'm thankful for.   :)

Comment: Are you trying to login as a same AD user who installed the CRM 2013?

Comment: @Scorpion Yes, I am. There are only three system users in the DB (System, Integration and me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comment above, it looks like installation issue.

Microsoft recommends that you add the Microsoft Dynamics CRM server to the PrivUserGroup group when you install the Microsoft Dynamics CRM server. If the server is manually removed from the group or if the server was not added during the installation, you experience the problem that is mentioned in the "Symptoms" section in the link below:

[Link 1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946620)

However this KB article is for 4.0 but it could be the same issue with 2013 as well. Worth reading.

**Update**

Also its worth checking application pool.

[Link 2](http://crm2011andsilverlight.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/microsoftcrmcrmexception-user-id-is.html)

Comment: Following the second link provided I wonder how one moves the appool to network services. I'm going to have to explain that to the maintenance  guys over the phone later...

Comment: Open IIS and go to Application Pool > Advanced Settings > Identity. Under built-in accounts you can see Network Service

Comment: Can you please tell me which solution worked for you. Regards

Comment: We put all the accounts to Network Service. I know, I know - it's like throwing in the towel. But next week, I intend to take a whack at it again and see if I can localize where exactly it went poof.